# split a file into half depending upon its number of lines

Tags: bash

I would like to split a main text file into two files. The text file has certain number of lines. Lets say NR.
I need two different file called as file 1 and file 2. File 1 is the upper half of the main text file. File 2 is the another half of the main text file.

Example:

Main text File

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
ddddd
eeeee
fffff
```

I need two file created from the main text file.

File 1 should be:

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
```

File 2 should be:

```
ddddd
eeeee
fffff
```

I have tried by using awk. But it did not work. Thanks all.

regards,

This i what I have done.

```
total_lines=$(cat ${band_file} | wc -l)
echo $total_lines
cat $band_file | awk '
{
  if(NR<=total_lines/2)
    print > "file 1"
  else
    print > "file 2"
}'
```

`

Comment: If you changed your example to read `... | awk -v total_lines=$total_lines ' ...` it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using only `awk` :

```
awk '
    {
        arr[NR]=$0
    }
    END{
        for (i=0; i<=NR; i++) {
            if (i < NR/2) {
                print arr[i] > "file1"
            }
            else {
                print arr[i] > "file2"
            }
        }
    }
' file.txt
```

So far,

```
$ ls file[0-9]
```

Comment: This is what have tried before asking the question to the form. I really appreciate for all your time and help.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '{ print > ( "file" (NR>(n/2) ? 2 : 1) ) }' n="$(wc -l <file)" file
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `split` for this:

```
split -n2 infile
```

`xaa` now contains:

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
```

and `xab` contains:

```
ddddd
eeeee
fffff
```

You can of course use awk, here's a fairly efficient alternative:

```
awk -v len=$(wc -l < infile) '
  BEGIN    { outfile = "file1"  } 
  NR>len/2 { outfile = "file2"  }
           { print $0 > outfile }
' infile
```

Comment: Noting that this is an extension in GNU `split`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It is supported by GNU and BSD split, don't know about others.

Answer (score 2):

Use [GNU Split](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html)

Example:

```
split -n 2 <file> # creates xaa & xab
```